# How to access QHeaderView::sectionsInserted slot

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to know how I can gain access to the sectionsInserted slot.I need access to the parameters of that method. Since it is a protected slot I think I would need to inherit from QHeaderView. Now even if I inherit from QheaderView how would I attach that Qheaderview to my tableview ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the vertical and horizontal headers of a QTableView with [QTableView::setVerticalHeader()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qtableview.html#setVerticalHeader) and [QTableView::setHorizontalHeader()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qtableview.html#setHorizontalHeader), respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `QAbstractItemModel::columnsInserted` or `QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted` signals instead. They have exactly the same signature. I believe they are connected to the `QHeaderView::sectionsInserted` slot.

Subclassing `QHeaderView` will not help you. `QHeaderView::columnsInserted` is not virtual, so your implementation will not be called by Qt.